# Rubymine debug [BUG] Segmentation fault

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

## Desc

I got [BUG] Segmentation fault
when i use rubymine5.4 to debug thor method :template

## context

- rubymine5.4
- ruby-debug-ide-0.4.18
- ruby 2.0.0
- thor 0.18-1

## code

```
#/home/zxr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/actions/file_manipulation.rb

def template(source, *args, &block)

  #i make a breakpoint in below line

  config = args.last.is_a?(Hash) ? args.pop : {}
  destination = args.first || source.sub(/\.tt$/, '')

  source  = File.expand_path(find_in_source_paths(source.to_s))
  context = instance_eval('binding')

  create_file destination, nil, config do
    content = ERB.new(::File.binread(source), nil, '-', '@output_buffer').result(context)
    content = block.call(content) if block
    content
  end
end
```

## got this error:

```
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.17, debase 0.0.7) listens on 127.0.0.1:36963
/home/zxr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17/lib/ruby-debug-ide/ide_processor.rb:27: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0027 p:---- s:0131 e:000130 CFUNC  :frame_binding
c:0026 p:0038 s:0127 e:000125 BLOCK  /home/zxr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17/lib/ruby-debug-ide/ide_processor.rb:27
c:0025 p:0026 s:0123 e:000122 METHOD /home/zxr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17/lib/ruby-debug-ide/ide_processor.rb:116 [FINISH]
c:0024 p:---- s:0120 e:000119 CFUNC  :new
c:0023 p:0105 s:0117 e:000116 METHOD /home/zxr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17/lib/ruby-debug-ide/ide_processor.rb:23
c:0022 p:0172 s:0108 e:000107 METHOD /home/zxr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17/lib/ruby-debug-ide/event_processor.rb:58
c:0021 p:0043 s:0101 e:000100 METHOD /home/zxr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17/lib/ruby-debug-ide/event_processor.rb:34
```

Comment: Try reinstalling `ruby-debug-ide` gem from the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the debug gem:

gem install ruby-debug-base19x --pre